# highcharts without jQuery and JSPM

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jspm

This question follow this issue closed on github because it isn't a bug : https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4677

I would like to use Highcharts in my project with the Highcharts adapter (to avoid jquery).

But, I'm building with JSPM, so the lib should normally provide some information to jspm/registry (https://github.com/jspm/registry) or document on how to do it, but I don't find anything on the library forum and on stack overflow.

Right now, I'm importing HighCharts like that : (https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/jspm/public/config/config.js)

```
...
import HighCharts from 'highcharts-release';
...
```

And I've registered it like that in JSPM | SystemJS :

```
System.config({
      baseURL: "./",
      defaultJSExtensions: true,
      transpiler: "babel",
      babelOptions: {
        "optional": [
          "runtime",
          "optimisation.modules.system"
        ]
      },
      paths: {
        "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
      },
      buildCSS: true,
      separateCSS: true,

      map: {
        "AngularStompDK": "github:davinkevin/AngularStompDK@0.3.2",
        "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7",
        "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.7",
        "angular-bootstrap": "github:angular-ui/bootstrap-bower@0.14.3",
        "angular-hotkeys": "github:chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys@1.4.5",
        "angular-loading-bar": "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@0.8.0",
        "angular-mocks": "npm:angular-mocks@1.4.7",
        "angular-notification": "github:neoziro/angular-notification@1.1.1",
        "angular-route": "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.7",
        "angular-sanitize": "github:angular/bower-angular-sanitize@1.4.7",
        "angular-touch": "github:angular/bower-angular-touch@1.4.7",
        "angular-truncate": "github:sparkalow/angular-truncate@master",
        "animate.css": "github:daneden/animate.css@3.4.0",
        "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.25",
        "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.25",
        "bootstrap-less": "github:distros/bootstrap-less@3.3.9",
        "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@3.4.6",
        "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.2",
        "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.19",
        "font-awesome": "github:components/font-awesome@4.4.0",
        "highcharts-ng": "github:pablojim/highcharts-ng@0.0.11",
        "highcharts-release": "github:highslide-software/highcharts-release@4.1.9",
        "ionicons": "github:driftyco/ionicons@2.0.1",
        "lodash": "github:lodash/lodash@3.10.1",
        "ng-file-upload": "github:danialfarid/ng-file-upload@9.1.1",
        "ng-tags-input": "github:mbenford/ngTagsInput@3.0.0",
        "ngstorage": "github:gsklee/ngStorage@0.3.9",
        "pablojim/highcharts-ng": "github:pablojim/highcharts-ng@0.0.11",
        "restangular": "github:mgonto/restangular@1.5.1",
        "sockjs-client": "github:sockjs/sockjs-client@0.3.4",
        "stomp-websocket": "github:jmesnil/stomp-websocket@2.3.4",
        "systemjs/plugin-text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.2",
        "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.2",
        "videogular": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular@1.3.2",
        "videogular-buffering": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular-buffering@1.3.2",
        "videogular-controls": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular-controls@1.3.2",
        "videogular-overlay-play": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular-overlay-play@1.3.2",
        "videogular-poster": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular-poster@1.3.2",
        "videogular-themes-default": "github:2fdevs/bower-videogular-themes-default@1.3.2",
        "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.7": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7"
        },
        "github:angular/bower-angular-route@1.4.7": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7"
        },
        "github:angular/bower-angular-sanitize@1.4.7": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7"
        },
        "github:angular/bower-angular-touch@1.4.7": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7"
        },
        "github:chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys@1.4.5": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7"
        },
        "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@0.8.0": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7",
          "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.19"
        },
        "github:distros/bootstrap-less@3.3.9": {
          "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
          "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
          "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.5.1"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
          "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1": {
          "Base64": "npm:Base64@0.2.1",
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
          "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0": {
          "https-browserify": "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0": {
          "os-browserify": "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
          "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
          "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
          "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0": {
          "url": "npm:url@0.10.3"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
          "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
        },
        "github:mbenford/ngTagsInput@3.0.0": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7",
          "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.19"
        },
        "github:mgonto/restangular@1.5.1": {
          "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.7",
          "lodash": "npm:lodash@3.10.1"
        },
        "npm:amdefine@1.0.0": {
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "module": "github:jspm/nodelibs-module@0.1.0",
          "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
          "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
        },
        "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.25": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:buffer@3.5.1": {
          "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
          "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
          "is-array": "npm:is-array@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:clean-css@3.4.6": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "commander": "npm:commander@2.8.1",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1",
          "https": "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0",
          "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0",
          "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "source-map": "npm:source-map@0.4.4",
          "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:commander@2.8.1": {
          "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "graceful-readlink": "npm:graceful-readlink@1.0.1",
          "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:core-js@1.2.2": {
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:core-util-is@1.0.1": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:graceful-readlink@1.0.1": {
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0": {
          "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1"
        },
        "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:lodash@3.10.1": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2": {
          "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:process@0.11.2": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:punycode@1.3.2": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.1",
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
          "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
        },
        "npm:source-map@0.4.4": {
          "amdefine": "npm:amdefine@1.0.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13"
        },
        "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:url@0.10.3": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
          "punycode": "npm:punycode@1.3.2",
          "querystring": "npm:querystring@0.2.0",
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:util@0.10.3": {
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        }
      }
    });
```

But when I load the project, logically nor jquery or the adapter are present, so the lib stop working with errors in console.

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: What was the solution? Did you make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a package override for **highcharts** where you add the **highcharts adapter** dependency to the main highcharts file using a **shim**. You can [this example](https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/CodeSeven/toastr%402.1.2.json) on how to do this.

I'm on a mobile phone so I cannot test this but I think that you'll need something like

```
`{
    "main": "highcharts ",
    "files": ["highcharts.js", "adapters"],
    "shim": {
        "highcharts": {
          "deps": ["./adapters/standalone-framework"]
        }
    }
}`
```

Not sure if this is what you were asking for though...

Comment: I've done the same on my main project : https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/master/package.json#L93

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you need to install jQuery and highcharts library by JSPM command.

```
$ jspm install jquery
$ jspm install npm:highcharts-release
```

You can import these in your `js` file

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'highcharts-release/highcharts.js';
```

Comment: I specified without jQuery in the title of my post, I want to use the highcharts-adapter.